# How can I see if a relationship of a core data entity has not been set?

Tags: ios, core-data

So, let's say I have an Entity and a Relationship on that Entity, as well as AttributeOne and AttributeTwo. How can I see if the Relationship has been set?

For the code below, I made sure to pre-fetch my relationship along with my fetch for the Entity, so that I know I'm not just getting a fault for the Relationship.

But the if condition seems to satisfy, regardless of whether the Relationship has been set or not.

```
if (Entity.Relationship != nil) {

    DLog(@"The relationship has been set");

}
```

When I run a po in the console to see the contents of the Relationship, this is what I get:

```
(lldb) po Entity.Relationship
Relationship 'Relationship' on managed object (0x7c647370) <Entity: 0x7c647370> (entity: Entity; id: 0x7c1c5cf0 <x-coredata:///Entity/tBBC33E0E-6A88-45D4-B4DD-F96794A33F282> ; data: {
    Relationship =     (
    );
    "AttributeOne" = 1;
    "AttributeTwo" = 2;
}) with objects {(
)}
```

This shows me that the Relationship has not been set, and looks empty to me. But the if condition from above still satisfies, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a to-many relationship, which is represented by `NSSet` instance. Instead of being `nil`, it was set to an empty `NSSet`.

If you want to know whether there are any objects in the `Relationship`, you can handle both cases checking the `count` of the relationship:

```
if(Entity.Relationship.count > 0) {

}
```